# Maven project Travis CI and Coveralls Integtation

Tags: github, travis-ci, coveralls

I have a private spring boot project stored in github. It's integated with Travis CI. I tried to integrate with coveralls and I added configuration scripts/tokens in .coveralls.yml and .travis.yml files.

The problem is that I can not see my coverage report anywhere.

**Coveralls web site**

```
There have been no builds for this repo.
```

**Travis Console Log**

```
[INFO] Successfully wrote Coveralls data in 109ms
[INFO] Gathered code coverage metrics for 31 source files with 1542 lines of code:
Successfully wrote Coveralls data in 109ms
[INFO] Gathered code coverage metrics for 31 source files with 1542 lines of code:
[INFO] - 431 relevant lines
[INFO] - 174 covered lines
[INFO] - 257 missed lines
[INFO] Submitting Coveralls data to API
[INFO] Successfully submitted Coveralls data in 643ms for Job #140.1
[INFO] https://coveralls.io/jobs/25499381
[INFO] *** It might take hours for Coveralls to update the actual coverage numbers for a job
[INFO]     If you see question marks in the report, please be patient
```

The project with related job id is not mine, but source files are related with my project

Comment: Any errors in the Travis log? Or a success message like `Submitting coverage to coveralls.io... - Coverage submitted! - Job #XXX.X - https://coveralls.io/jobs/XXXXXX` ? Does the the coveralls site of your project shows any build?

Comment: @Nef10 I updated the question with details.

Comment: isn't there a link in to coveralls in the output like in my example?

Comment: @Nef10 I updated the details again.

Comment: It seems like it is pushing to a wrong repository (your repository is not `STARCRAFTMAN / PAKIT`, right?) Are you sure the config in the  .coveralls.yml and .travis.yml files is correct? Maybe you can share it with us (mask all sensitive content in there)?

Comment: Yeah, absolutely wrong repository. I have  this config just in coveralls file not travis file.

Comment: As you wrote that you have a private repo, might it be [this issue](https://github.com/lemurheavy/coveralls-public/issues/357) ?